# M2.3.7 Change custom maintenance page title

Tags: maintenance, magento2.3.7

I want to change the page title of my custom maintenance page.

I already found out that the title is set hard in `pub/errors/processor.php` in the `Processor::process503()` method.

The `$pageTitle` member is public so I would be able to set it from outside of the object, weren't it that the method returns a `Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http` object directly.

**processor.php:**

```
public function process503()
{
    $this->pageTitle = 'Error 503: Service Unavailable';
    $this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(503);
    $this->_response->setBody($this->_renderPage('503.phtml'));
    return $this->_response;
}
```

**503.php:**

There's no place here where I could set the `$pageTitle` member from outside because `process503()` will overwrite it.

```
require_once 'processorFactory.php';

$processorFactory = new \Magento\Framework\Error\ProcessorFactory();
$processor = $processorFactory->createProcessor();
$response = $processor->process503();
$response->sendResponse();
```

Is there any way I can change the page title without editing core files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is more customization, than workaround, but it's allow you to don't overwrite core and keep you logic in theme.

1. copy files from `pub/errors/default` directory into your custom theme like `pub/errors/acme`
2. Create local theme configuration `pub/errors/local.xml`

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <skin>acme</skin>
   </config>
   ```
3. Customize `pub/errors/acme/page.phtml` in way like

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */

   $pageTitle = $this->pageTitle;
   if ($pageTitle === 'Error 503: Service Unavailable') {
       $pageTitle = 'Custom Service Unavailable Title';
   }
   ?>
   <!doctype html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
   <head>
       <title><?= $pageTitle ?></title>
       <base href="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl() ?>" />
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <meta name="robots" content="*"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
       <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <main class="page-main">
           <?php require_once $contentTemplate; ?>
       </main>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: I didn't like to check on the actual title, so I made it to check on the http response code: 

`<title>Store name <?php if ($this->_response->getHttpResponseCode() === 503): ?>| We are busy remodelling our store<?php elseif ($this->_response->getHttpResponseCode() === 404): ?>| Something went wrong<?php endif; ?></title>`

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so I made a workaround.

I extended `\Magento\Framework\Error\Processor` and override `process503()`. Then I edited `503.php` to use the custom class.

**customProcessor.php**

```php
require_once  realpath(__DIR__) . '/processor.php';

class CustomProcessor extends \Magento\Framework\Error\Processor
{
    public function process503()
    {
        $this->pageTitle = 'We zijn even bezig';
        $this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(503);
        $this->_response->setBody($this->_renderPage('503.phtml'));
        return $this->_response;
    }
}
```

**503.php**

```
require_once realpath(__DIR__) . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
require_once realpath(__DIR__) . '/customProcessor.php';

$objectManagerFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::createObjectManagerFactory(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $objectManagerFactory->create($_SERVER);
$response = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http::class);
$processor = new CustomProcessor($response);
$response = $processor->process503();
$response->sendResponse();
```

I'm still looking for a "real" solution so please share if you know!

Comment: This is overwrite core file. If you've reinstall your vendors with composer, composer will overwrite your changes.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk do you have any suggestions how to do it without editing core files? The files are included directly so I couldn't make a custom module and override the class with di.xml